# AIR Application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, splash-screen

I have my AIR application i.e MyAIRApplication ready. I am trying to make a splash screen for it.
Here's my code so far ..

**main.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
                        creationComplete="showSplash()" 
                        visible="false"
                        layout="absolute"
                        showFlexChrome="false">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import components.Splash;

            import mx.core.Window;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.AIREvent;

            private var splash:Window;
            private var splashTimer:Timer;

            private function showSplash():void {
                splash = new Splash();
                splash.systemChrome = "none";
                splash.transparent = true;

                splash.type = NativeWindowType.LIGHTWEIGHT;
                splash.addEventListener(AIREvent.WINDOW_COMPLETE, boot);
                splash.open();
            }

            private function boot(event:AIREvent):void {
                splashTimer = new Timer(3000, 2);
                splashTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, showApp);
                splashTimer.start();
                this.removeEventListener(AIREvent.WINDOW_COMPLETE, boot);

            }

            private function showApp(event:Event):void {
                splash.close();
                splash = null;

                splashTimer.stop();
                splashTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, showApp);
                splashTimer = null;

                // My Application .. where I wrote all components
                var mainWin:WindowedApplication = new MyAIRApplication();
                mainWin.activate();
                mainWin.visible = true;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

**Splash.mxml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Window xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="400" height="300"
           showFlexChrome="false" >
    <mx:Image x="0" y="0" width="600" height="400" source="@Embed('../images/splash-bg.png')" scaleContent="false"/>

</mx:Window>
```

But I am facing 2 problems :

1. My AIR application ( i.e MyAIRApplication ) is not showing up, on completing the splash screen.
2. My Splash Screen is getting shown on top left corner always

Can anyone please provide me with a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `var mainWin:WindowedApplication = new MyAIRApplication();`

WindowedApplication isn't created like this. You already have one when your app start, use it. Just make its contents hidden to be shown after the splash.
Also I'm not sure that closing splash window with `splash.close()` will fire WINDOW_COMPLETE event, check this too with `trace` (rewrite to Event.CLOSE if needed.)

1. Windows aren't centered by default. Get screen size with `Capabilities.screenResolutionX/Y`, calculate x/y for centered window and call `splash.move(x, y)`.

Answer (score 0):

It also might have something to do with you casting your splash var as type Window,

```
private var splash:Window;
```

But then instantiating it as a new Splash

```
private function showSplash():void {
                splash = new Splash();
```

They should both be either Window or Splash.